What is the error of this assembly program
I wrote this code to calculate the count of chars in input. but i only get 0 as output. can someone check and tell what the error is
section .data
    msg db "Enter the text: ", 0
    msg_len equ $ - msg

    newline db "0a", 0
    newline_len equ $ - newline

section .bss
    buffer1 resb 100
    buffer2 resb 2

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, msg
    mov rdx, msg_len
    syscall

    ; get input
    mov rax, 0
    mov rdi, 0
    mov rsi, buffer1
    mov rdx, 100
    syscall

; char cal part
    mov rdi, buffer1
    xor rcx, rcx
    xor rbx, rbx

loop_start:
    mov al, [rdi + rbx]
    cmp al, 0x0a
    je found
    inc rcx
    inc rbx
    cmp al, 0x0a
    jne loop_start

found:
    add rcx, '0'
    mov [buffer2], rcx
    call print
    
print:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, [buffer2]
    mov rdx, 1
    syscall
    
    call exit
    
exit:
    ; Print newline character
        mov rax, 1       ; syscall number for sys_write
        mov rdi, 1       ; file descriptor 1 is stdout
        mov rsi, newline ; address of the newline character
        mov rdx, 1       ; length of the data to print
        syscall          ; invoke syscall   

    mov rax, 60
    xor rdi, rdi
    syscall

when i check this code with radare2 all things work perfectly. but when i run only 0 get outputed.I put a new line character too. I'm suspicious about the print function. is the rdx value right?
EDIT
I changed the code a bit and now it's working. But i can only get the count for 0-9 range words. Can anyone suggest a good way to get output of count by iterating through loop.

Changed code is:

section .data
    msg db "Enter the text: ", 0
    msg_len equ $ - msg

    newline db "0a", 0
    newline_len equ $ - newline

    num db 1           

; put buffer2 in data section as "num"

section .bss
    buffer1 resb 10


buffer2 resb 2 Two bytes reserved.  mov [buffer2], rcx: store of 8 bytes, because rcx is a 64-bit register.  That's not good.

mov rsi, [buffer2] before syscall should be mov rsi, buffer2.  You need rsi to contain the address of the buffer, not 8 bytes of its contents.

radare2 is a disassembler; what do you mean by "checking" the code with it?  I think the tool you want is a debugger so that you can single-step your program, inspecting register and memory contents as you go.  Then you'll be able to see exactly which instruction is not doing what you expected, rather than having to infer it from the program's output.

Could you please highlight the differences between the two versions of your code (e.g. with comments on the differing lines)?  It's hard to see at a glance.

Thanks for checking in. I changed the code by bringing the buffer2 var into the data section, and now the code runs. But still, I can only count 0-9. Do you know how to iterate and get the decimal value as output

Convert binary to decimal by repeatedly dividing by 10, and store them in a buffer in reverse order, then write to standard output at the end.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info under "How do I handle multi-digit numbers?" for some links to examples.
